# Why is flink SplitStream marked deprecated

Tags: apache-flink

Why is flink SplitStream marked deprecated?
Will the stream be removed in the future?
Or what else is there to replace this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Side outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/side_output.html) are more flexible and more efficient than split/select.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's not documented, but, I found the Pull Request which deprecated this class. https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/e0efabe8884f22b4a1c7ab9df3274b3fca03dcfb#diff-163a9f7f1b682eab706eb5e2a94faabcR36

By looking this PR you will see that it's missing the following description: `Please use side ouput instead.`

Looks like they forgot to add why and what to use instead.