# Apache Flink: SpiltStream vs side outputs

Tags: apache-flink

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56378864/why-is-flink-splitstream-marked-deprecated), I understand that SplitStream in Apache Flink is now deprecated and it's recommended to use [side-outputs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/) instead.
Can someone give an example of how side-output can replace the splitStream?

e.g. How can the code snippet below be modified to use side-output?

```
        DataStream mainDataStream = some definition
        SplitStream<some-type> splitStream = mainDataStream.select("some-string")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than

```java
SplitStream<Integer> split = someDataStream.split(new OutputSelector<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public Iterable<String> select(Integer value) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            output.add("even");
        }
        else {
            output.add("odd");
        }
        return output;
    }
});

DataStream<Integer> evens = split.select("even");
DataStream<Integer> odds = split.select("odd");
```

you can now do

```java
final OutputTag<Integer> evenTag = new OutputTag<String>("even"){};
final OutputTag<Integer> oddTag = new OutputTag<String>("odd"){};

SingleOutputStreamOperator<Integer> mainDataStream = someDataStream
    .process(new ProcessFunction<Integer, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void processElement(
          Integer value,
          Context ctx,
          Collector<Integer> out) throws Exception {

          if (value % 2 == 0) {
              ctx.output(evenTag, value);
          } else {
              ctx.output(oddTag, value);
          }
   });

DataStream<Integer> evens = mainDataStream.getSideOutput(evenTag);
DataStream<Integer> odds = mainDataStream.getSideOutput(oddTag);
```

Note that, unlike split streams, the side output streams can be of different types.